# OpenCV configuration for image processing on eclipse

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to build the *myopencv* project and I encountered this error:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1ec): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::String const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: add more details in description as to how you tried to add the opencv lib.

Comment: i added on eclipse project properties->c++ build->settings->Mingw c++ linker->librarires. library search path-> "C:\Users\tamer\Desktop\opencv\sources\release\lib".libraries(-l) i added opencv_core310 and opencv_highgui310.i hav followed this video tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyVEHK4qfQ

Answer (score 0):

`cv::putText` is in `opencv_imgproc`, not core or highgui.  You need to add `opencv_imgproc310` to your libraries list.